# Elasticsearch url from Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-5

I am trying to find out the url of the elasticsearch configured in kibana.
but i dont have access to the backend configurations.
Is there a way to see which elasticsearch url has been configured in kibana using the kibana front end.

Thanks

Comment: No, I dont think so. Kibana REST API also does not allow reading or modifying config file. Unless you have access to Kibana instance I dont think you can find out the ES end point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have access to the Monitoring you could use Dev Tools and query all nodes in the connected ES cluster using query GET /_nodes, like this:
[image: screenshot with GET /_nodes command]

Answer (score 3):

Use `GET /` in the kibana console and this will give your elastic search database url name.

Comment: i don't see kibana console.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the X-Pack Monitoring plugin enabled, you can go to "Monitoring > Elasticsearch > Nodes" and you can see the nodes that are reachable from Kibana.